# how to query list of list in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I got data from DB.

```
final List<SubCategoryModel> model;
```

my model class looks like this:

```
class SubCategoryModel{
  final String categoryName;
  final String subCategoryName;
  final List<String> searchCategory;
}
```

Users can search `categoryName` or `subCategoryName` or any other common name. I stored common search names inside `searchCategory`. `searchCategory` is an array.

I don't understand query `searchCategory` in DB. Currently, I used this:

```
  final result =
        model.where((a) => a.subCategoryName.toLowerCase().contains(query)
        || a.categoryName.toLowerCase().contains(query));
```

**Widget**

```
 ListView(
            children: result
                .map<InkWell>((a) => InkWell(...
```

> Example:
>
> CategoryName = Home
>
> SubCategoryName = Kitchen
>
> searchCategory = [Home,Service,Varanda,Bath Room]
>
> Need to query from above three field

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: @PhucTran I edit my question..

Comment: I still don't understand your issue

Comment: @PhucTran I added my own answer. It's working now. can you check it? if you have best solution let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a method for checking `SearchCategory` list

```
  bool checkList(SubCategoryModel cat,String q){
    for(int i = 0; i < cat. searchCategory.length;i++){
      if(cat. searchCategory[i].toLowerCase().contains(q))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

change query like this

```
 final result = model.where((a) =>
        a.subCategoryName.toLowerCase().contains(query) ||
        a.categoryName.toLowerCase().contains(query) || checkList(a,query));
```